# How can you use C# parameter modifiers from Haxe?

Tags: c#, parameters, haxe

I'm currently porting my C# code to Haxe, but am having difficulty discerning how to use C# parameter modifiers such as Out or Ref from Haxe

For example, the Out parameter is used in functions like TryGetValue in many of the C# Generic collections. In the example below using Haxe, it passes Haxe compilation but complains when compiling with the Mono compiler that an Out modifier is required, which is what I had thought it was doing.

**Example Code**

```
// In C#, looks like this..`.
KeyValuePair<T,V>? element = null;
if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out element))
{
     // Do foo
}

// In Haxe?
var element:Out<KeyValuePair<T,V>> = null;
if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, element))
{
     // Do foo
}
```

**Links to the Parameter Typedefs in Haxe for Parameter Modifiers in C#**

- http://api.haxe.org/cs/Out.html
- http://api.haxe.org/cs/Ref.html

Is there anyone who can show me the proper way to use the Haxe typedefs for parameter modifiers in Haxe? Thank you.

Comment: AS far as I know there is no such thing in haxe, what you can do is to make the function returns that element and assign it to element

Comment: This isn't replicating that feature in haxe; In C#, a common function call to the Dictionary collection in Systems.Collection.Generics is TryGetValue, where one of the parameters has to be specified as an out parameter. I want to know how to call that native C# function from Haxe.

Comment: I think you can use the __cs__ constructor which enable you to embed c# code.

var str:String = "test untyped";
var s = untyped __cs__("System.Console.WriteLine(str)");

more info : http://old.haxe.org/doc/advanced/magic

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the doc, the `Out` type is meant to be used in function parameters only. So basically you only need to type your variable normally.

The following code works for me:

```
import cs.system.collections.generic.Dictionary_2;

class Main {
    static function main() {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary_2<String, Foo>();
        dictionary.Add('haxe', new Foo());

        // type inference works
        var implicit = null;
        dictionary.TryGetValue('haxe', implicit);
        trace(implicit);

        // this also works
        var explicit:Foo = null;
        dictionary.TryGetValue('haxe', explicit);
        trace(explicit);
    }
}

class Foo {
    public function new() {}
}
```